# Can I use .natvis file to always display uintptr_t as hex?

Tags: natvis

I'm probably just not searching well enough, but its unclear to me how (or if its possible) to specify that the variable should be displayed in a particular way.  All the examples are structs or classes with member variables, but uintptr_t has none.

Is it?

Answer (score 0):

As the [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/create-custom-views-of-native-objects?view=vs-2022) say

> **Note**
> Natvis customizations work with classes and structs, but not typedefs.

`uintptr_t` is a `typedef unsigned __int64  uintptr_t;`.

So no, this is not possible in Visual Studio.

You can of course wrap the `uintptr_t` in your own struct/class and then write a natvis visualizer for your struct/class, displaying the contained `uintptr_t` as hex.